# Handling Web User Control error on asp.net page

Tags: asp.net

How do you handle the Web User Control event? I notice my custom web user control have a event call OnError but it never fire when i tweak the control to fail. The control is basically a custom gridview control. I search for web user control event handling over the net but i haven't find a article that address what i looking for. Can someone do a quick explanation or point me to the right direction?

thank

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention what flavour of ASP.NET, so I'll make the assumption of VB - C# is largely the same with the exception of how the event handler is attached.

The normal pattern you would expect to see is something along these lines:

***User Control "MyUserControl" CodeBehind***

```
Public Event MyEvent(ByVal Sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

Private Sub SomeMethodThatRaisesMyEvent()
  RaiseEvent MyEvent(Me, New EventArgs)
End Sub
```

***Page Designer Code***

```
Private WithEvents MyUserControl1 As System.Web.UI.UserControls.MyUserControl
```

***Page or other Control that wraps MyUserControl instance CodeBehind***

```
Private Sub MyUserControlEventHandler(ByVal Sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) _
  Handles MyUserControl.MyEvent

    Response.Write("My event handled")

End Sub
```

In some instances, you see something called Event Bubbling which doesn't follow this kind of pattern exactly.  But in the basic sense of handling events from a user control to a wrapper control or the page it sits in, that's how you would expect it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue with a custom control that was throwing exceptions which were not firing `Error` event. Thus I could not catch exceptions from this control and display appropriate message in the ASP.NET page.

Here is what I did. I wrapped the code in the custom control in a `try..catch` block and fired the `Error` event myself, like this:

```
// within the custom control
try
{
    // do something that raises an exception
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    OnError(EventArgs.Empty); // let parent ASP.NET page handle it in the
        // Error event
}
```

The ASP.NET page was handling the exception using the `Error` event like this:

```
<script runat="server">
    void MyCustomControl_Error(object source, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyCustomControl c = source as MyCustomControl;

        if (c != null)
        {
            // Notice that you cannot retrieve the Exception
            // using Server.GetLastError() as it will return null

            Server.ClearError();
            c.Visible = false;

            // All I wanted to do in this case was to hide the control
        }
    }
</script>

<sd:MyCustomControl OnError="MyCustomControl_Error" runat="server" />
```