# ASP.NET UserControl OnError

Tags: asp.net, exception, user-controls

UserControls in ASP.NET (4.0) inherit from System.Web.UI.UserControl. VisualStudio intellisense suggest OnError as valid override of TemplateControl. At runtime .NET ignores this error handling. Only the OnError at Page-Level gets invoked. Did i miss anything or is there a design issue?

```
public partial class Sample : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    protected override void OnError(EventArgs e)
    {
        // Never reach ;o)
        base.OnError(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/341417/handling-web-user-control-error-on-asp-net-page

Comment: @deniz dogan: i could not use an errorhandling outside the control. it need to be an internal fallback. it's also not possible to attach on the error event in OnInit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ah.. the elusive OnError

this page sheds some good light on the inner workings of this event:

http://weblogs.asp.net/vga/archive/2003/06/16/8748.aspx

it may be that some exceptions are caught w/out triggering OnError

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to override OnError? You'd probably be better off by using a try/catch block or subscribing to the [Application_Error](http://www.15seconds.com/issue/030102.htm) event.

Comment: because you'd need to wrap EVERY operation in try/catch.. OnError should automatically notify you of any problems, if that's what you're using it for. try/catch is suitable when you know what error might cause the exception and how to handle that situation.